# It it correct to reexport std library from the cpp module?

Tags: c++, c++20

I want to use C++20 modules with MSVC compiler and with CMake. It seems to be pretty hard and not unversal to setup standard library headers compilation as module units, so I did the following:

`stdlib.ixx`:

```cpp
export module stdlib;

export import std.core; // std.core is MSVC specific thing
```

`main.cpp`:

```cpp
import stdlib;

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> vec = { "Hello, world 1!", "Hello, world 2!" };

    for (const auto& v : vec) {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(test1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_compile_options(/experimental:module /translateInclude)

add_executable(test1 main.cpp stdlib.ixx)
```

Seems that this code works right, but it is correct/good/appropriate solution accoring to modern C++?

Comment: It will be simply `import std;` for C++23 once compilers have implemented it.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but I want to use C++ modules now, but the timing of the implementation of this feature is unknown.